# From the Shockley Ideal Diode Equation show that

Tags: homework-and-exercises, terminology, semiconductor-physics

I was reading an article which stated the following (I can't link to the article, apologies):

The Shockley idea diode equation is

$I = I_0( e^{\frac{qV}{kT}}-1)$         (1)

And it can be shown that

$I_0 = AT^{3 + \gamma/2}exp(-E_g(T)/kT)$                 (2)

Where A is a constant and $E_g$ is the energy gap.

Subbing (2) into (1) it can be shown that for qV>3kT, taking the [Napierian logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napierian_logarithm) and multiplying both sides by kT,

$qV = E_g + T[kln(I/A)-(3+\gamma/2)kln(T)]$     (3)

What is the napierian logarithm? I assumed it was the natural log but then I couldn't get to the final result. Could someone show me how to get from (1) and (2) to (3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition qV>3kT means that the -1 can be neglected in equation (1). Then (1) is only an exponential function. When you take the natural logarithm on both sides of (1) and use the expression (2) for I0, you will obtain the result of equation (3).

Comment: Thanks! Why does qV>3kT mean that though?

Comment: @Karacoreable - For qV ≳ 3kT the exponential function is much larger than 1 [exp(qV/kT) ≳ 20]. qV ≳ 3kT is a common condition to neglect the 1 compared to the exponential function in ideal diode equations.